# Downloading data into specific folders

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a number of `urls`. I am writing some code to tell R to go to the `url` and download it. However I want to be a little organised so I want to save the `urls` into a folder depending on the year it was collected from. That is I have a column in the data called `filing_date_year`.

So if the `url` was collected from the `year 2003` then I want to save the `url` in a folder called `2003`. However if the year was `2010` then I would like to save the document in a folder called `2010`.

`########################################################################`

I have the following code:

```
library(purrr)
walk2(data_information_documents_toget$href.y, data_information_documents_toget$CIKAccNumFileDate_web_extension,
      function(x, y) {
        download.file(x, destfile = paste0("c:/USER/directory/",year_to_filter, "/", y), quiet = FALSE)
      })
```

Which takes from a data frame called `data_information_documents_toget` the `url` where the document is located `href.y`. I want to download this `url` and save it with a unique ID name `CIKAccNumFileDate_web_extension`

I am trying to add the condition `year_to_filter` which will essentially be the index to say if the `url` was taken from the row with the year `2003` then save it in the `2003` folder etc.

Sample Data:

```
data_information_documents_toget <- structure(list(href.y = c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1578845/000156459019003111/agn-10k_20181231.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/81033/000093041308001260/c52299_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/704051/000070405115000045/lm_10kx3312015.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/5133/000119312513209085/d460905d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/915912/000095012310019013/w77522e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/823768/000095012311015242/h76657e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/12978/000104746905006771/a2153651z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/12659/000095013707009521/c16312e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/941548/000095012904001055/h13049e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000104746913001180/a2212523z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1004155/000100415506000097/form10ka.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/5272/000000527215000002/maindocument001.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1308161/000156459018021493/fox-10k_20180630.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/915389/000091538917000014/emn2016123110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1326380/000132638015000078/form10k-fy14.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/85408/000095012907001047/h43875e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1224608/000122460816000053/cno1231201510-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/836106/000089161804000704/f95884e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1040971/000110465905011116/a05-4733_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/909832/000119312505223245/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/723254/000110465906053974/a06-16851_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1037038/000103703815000006/rl-20150328x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1113169/000095013308000389/w47962e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/808450/000119312509257118/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/909832/000119312511271844/d203874d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/319201/000144530511002394/klac10k2011.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/915912/000091591218000004/a201710-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/95304/000095010903001224/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3153/000009212211000013/g24641xxe10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/12659/000095013706004022/c03876e10vkza.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/63541/000119312506027038/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1585689/000158568914000006/a2013hwh10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1099800/000104746908001956/a2183020z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/49196/000095015208001408/l29571ae10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1101215/000110121519000048/ads-20181231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1310067/000119312510055594/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1174922/000119312512195995/d340198d10ka.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/69970/000095015208004633/l32075ae10vkza.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/5272/000104746914001096/a2218248z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1058090/000105809016000058/cmg-20151231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/885639/000088563913000004/kohls_10kx2012.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/354964/000035496413000002/hbio12311210-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1075531/000110465911010302/a11-2103_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/54480/000119312511028728/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1004434/000104746903011288/a2106221z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1526520/000119312514045532/d654086d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1310067/000131006715000009/shld201410k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4962/000119312513070554/d486442d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/354950/000104746907002295/a2176777z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/823768/000119312516467957/d83265d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/50104/000095013409004250/d66470e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1437107/000095013309000442/w72867e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/791519/000104746905004527/a2152243z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1136893/000089256908000207/a38312e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1141391/000119312511320907/d258542d10ka.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1365135/000136513518000013/wu-12312017x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/60667/000006066706000141/lowesform10ka02032006.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090727/000119312512081067/d274494d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/80424/000095015205007351/l15436ae10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/108772/000010877218000012/xrx-123117x10xk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1075531/000110465904007430/a04-3266_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/318154/000031815417000004/amgn-12312016x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1442145/000095012311019814/y89886e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/5513/000000551318000016/unm12312017-10xk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1437107/000143710714000016/disca-2013123110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1466258/000146625819000073/ir-10kx12312018.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/50104/000005010417000056/tso201610-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1166691/000119312506036698/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1141982/000095012311016589/h78025e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/37785/000003778517000011/fmc201610k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1040971/000104746909005369/a2192961z10-ka.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/39911/000119312509066067/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1045810/000104581018000010/nvda-2018x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1370946/000137094617000006/oc-20161231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/936340/000095012405001542/k91838e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/316709/000031670916000067/schw-20151231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/25445/000144530514000574/cr-20131231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1336917/000133691718000009/ua-20171231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6281/000095013507007253/b67578ade10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/879169/000110465907015059/a07-5374_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1039684/000103968412000027/form_10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/31235/000003123511000025/ek2010_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1004434/000104746909002123/a2190957z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/818479/000081847909000034/q40810k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1121788/000161577419002739/s116041_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/766704/000095015209002082/l35635ae10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/29534/000104746913003283/a2213303z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/865436/000086543614000161/wfm10k2014.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/5272/000110465912013132/a11-32502_410ka.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/931336/000095013403009830/d06474a1e10vkza.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1037646/000095012311014519/l41517e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1020569/000110465906017231/a06-2602_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1496048/000149604817000018/ggp12311610k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1169055/000162828018002128/noblecorpplc-201710xk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/920760/000162828018000562/len-20171130x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/28917/000002891718000159/dds-02032018x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/875320/000087532019000006/a201810k-main.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1359841/000135984117000040/hbi-20161231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/20520/000002052015000011/ftr-20141231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1495569/000119312511040013/d10k.htm"
), CIKAccNumFileDate_web_extension = c("0000054480_0001564590-19-003111_2019-02-15.htm", 
"0000788784_0000930413-08-001260_2008-02-28.htm", "0001000180_0000704051-15-000045_2015-05-22.htm", 
"0001094093_0001193125-13-209085_2013-05-09.htm", "0000314808_0000950123-10-019013_2010-03-01.htm", 
"0000029534_0000950123-11-015242_2011-02-17.htm", "0001585689_0001047469-05-006771_2005-03-16.htm", 
"0000028917_0000950137-07-009521_2007-06-29.htm", "0000721683_0000950129-04-001055_2004-03-08.htm", 
"0000001800_0001047469-13-001180_2013-02-15.htm", "0001141982_0001004155-06-000097_2006-06-01.htm", 
"0001115222_0000005272-15-000002_2015-02-20.htm", "0001272547_0001564590-18-021493_2018-08-13.htm", 
"0001166691_0000915389-17-000014_2017-02-27.htm", "0001053507_0001326380-15-000078_2015-03-30.htm", 
"0000095521_0000950129-07-001047_2007-02-28.htm", "0000785161_0001224608-16-000053_2016-02-19.htm", 
"0000819692_0000891618-04-000704_2004-03-12.htm", "0000006201_0001104659-05-011116_2005-03-15.htm", 
"0000860730_0001193125-05-223245_2005-11-10.htm", "0000020520_0001104659-06-053974_2006-08-11.htm", 
"0000915912_0001037038-15-000006_2015-05-15.htm", "0000006281_0000950133-08-000389_2008-02-07.htm", 
"0000063541_0001193125-09-257118_2009-12-21.htm", "0000860730_0001193125-11-271844_2011-10-14.htm", 
"0001400891_0001445305-11-002394_2011-08-05.htm", "0000314808_0000915912-18-000004_2018-02-23.htm", 
"0000040704_0000950109-03-001224_2003-03-07.htm", "0000092122_0000092122-11-000013_2011-02-25.htm", 
"0000028917_0000950137-06-004022_2006-03-31.htm", "0000026780_0001193125-06-027038_2006-02-10.htm", 
"0001598014_0001585689-14-000006_2014-02-27.htm", "0001385187_0001047469-08-001956_2008-02-29.htm", 
"0000812074_0000950152-08-001408_2008-02-26.htm", "0000851968_0001101215-19-000048_2019-02-26.htm", 
"0001310067_0001193125-10-055594_2010-03-12.htm", "0000818479_0001193125-12-195995_2012-04-30.htm", 
"0000883980_0000950152-08-004633_2008-06-16.htm", "0001115222_0001047469-14-001096_2014-02-20.htm", 
"0001364742_0001058090-16-000058_2016-02-05.htm", "0001007456_0000885639-13-000004_2013-03-22.htm", 
"0000006201_0000354964-13-000002_2013-03-04.htm", "0001274494_0001104659-11-010302_2011-02-25.htm", 
"0000018926_0001193125-11-028728_2011-02-09.htm", "0001168054_0001047469-03-011288_2003-03-31.htm", 
"0000935703_0001193125-14-045532_2014-02-11.htm", "0001310067_0001310067-15-000009_2015-03-17.htm", 
"0001122304_0001193125-13-070554_2013-02-22.htm", "0000714154_0001047469-07-002295_2007-03-29.htm", 
"0000029534_0001193125-16-467957_2016-02-18.htm", "0001571949_0000950134-09-004250_2009-03-02.htm", 
"0000046765_0000950133-09-000442_2009-02-26.htm", "0000875570_0001047469-05-004527_2005-02-24.htm", 
"0000816284_0000892569-08-000207_2008-02-29.htm", "0001430602_0001193125-11-320907_2011-11-23.htm", 
"0001156375_0001365135-18-000013_2018-02-22.htm", "0001037949_0000060667-06-000141_2006-09-29.htm", 
"0000352510_0001193125-12-081067_2012-02-27.htm", "0000080424_0000950152-05-007351_2005-08-29.htm", 
"0000108772_0000108772-18-000012_2018-02-23.htm", "0001274494_0001104659-04-007430_2004-03-15.htm", 
"0000043362_0000318154-17-000004_2017-02-14.htm", "0001166691_0000950123-11-019814_2011-02-28.htm", 
"0000091576_0000005513-18-000016_2018-02-21.htm", "0000916076_0001437107-14-000016_2014-02-20.htm", 
"0000896159_0001466258-19-000073_2019-02-12.htm", "0001571949_0000050104-17-000056_2017-02-21.htm", 
"0001275283_0001193125-06-036698_2006-02-22.htm", "0001466258_0000950123-11-016589_2011-02-22.htm", 
"0001087423_0000037785-17-000011_2017-02-28.htm", "0000006201_0001047469-09-005369_2009-05-11.htm", 
"0000053117_0001193125-09-066067_2009-03-27.htm", "0000792985_0001045810-18-000010_2018-02-28.htm", 
"0001370946_0001370946-17-000006_2017-02-08.htm", "0000936340_0000950124-05-001542_2005-03-15.htm", 
"0000721371_0000316709-16-000067_2016-02-24.htm", "0000107681_0001445305-14-000574_2014-02-25.htm", 
"0000850209_0001336917-18-000009_2018-02-28.htm", "0000764622_0000950135-07-007253_2007-11-30.htm", 
"0001681459_0001104659-07-015059_2007-02-28.htm", "0001039684_0001039684-12-000027_2012-02-21.htm", 
"0000934612_0000031235-11-000025_2011-02-25.htm", "0001168054_0001047469-09-002123_2009-03-02.htm", 
"0001378946_0000818479-09-000034_2009-02-20.htm", "0000029534_0001615774-19-002739_2019-02-20.htm", 
"0001020569_0000950152-09-002082_2009-03-02.htm", "0001593538_0001047469-13-003283_2013-03-25.htm", 
"0001339947_0000865436-14-000161_2014-11-21.htm", "0001115222_0001104659-12-013132_2012-02-27.htm", 
"0001652044_0000950134-03-009830_2003-07-03.htm", "0001659166_0000950123-11-014519_2011-02-16.htm", 
"0000812074_0001104659-06-017231_2006-03-16.htm", "0001393612_0001496048-17-000018_2017-02-22.htm", 
"0000711065_0001628280-18-002128_2018-02-23.htm", "0000820027_0001628280-18-000562_2018-01-25.htm", 
"0001613103_0000028917-18-000159_2018-03-30.htm", "0001037868_0000875320-19-000006_2019-02-13.htm", 
"0001101239_0001359841-17-000040_2017-02-03.htm", "0001017008_0000020520-15-000011_2015-02-25.htm", 
"0001702780_0001193125-11-040013_2011-02-18.htm"), name = c("KANSAS CITY SOUTHERN", 
"PUBLIC SERVICE ENTERPRISE GROUP INC", "SANDISK CORP", "PROGRESS ENERGY INC", 
"Ensco plc", "DOLLAR GENERAL CORP", "Hilton Worldwide Holdings Inc.", 
"DILLARD'S, INC.", "TOTAL SYSTEM SERVICES INC", "ABBOTT LABORATORIES", 
"Cooper Industries plc", "DUN & BRADSTREET CORP/NW", "FREESCALE SEMICONDUCTOR INC", 
"COMCAST CORP", "AMERICAN TOWER CORP /MA/", "SUPERVALU INC", 
"Encompass Health Corp", "CHARTER ONE FINANCIAL INC", "American Airlines Group Inc.", 
"HCA Healthcare, Inc.", "FRONTIER COMMUNICATIONS CORP", "AVALONBAY COMMUNITIES INC", 
"ANALOG DEVICES INC", "MAYTAG CORP", "HCA Healthcare, Inc.", 
"iHeartMedia, Inc.", "Ensco plc", "GENERAL MILLS INC", "SOUTHERN CO", 
"DILLARD'S, INC.", "DANA INC", "IHS Markit Ltd.", "Covidien plc", 
"OWENS ILLINOIS INC /DE/", "MOHAWK INDUSTRIES INC", "SEARS HOLDINGS CORP", 
"DENTSPLY SIRONA Inc.", "FIRST DATA CORP", "DUN & BRADSTREET CORP/NW", 
"BlackRock Inc.", "ELECTRONIC DATA SYSTEMS CORP /DE/", "American Airlines Group Inc.", 
"FIRST SOLAR, INC.", "CENTURYLINK, INC", "CIMAREX ENERGY CO", 
"DOLLAR TREE INC", "SEARS HOLDINGS CORP", "AETNA INC /PA/", "COMPAQ COMPUTER CORP", 
"DOLLAR GENERAL CORP", "Intercontinental Exchange, Inc.", "Helmerich & Payne, Inc.", 
"PEOPLESOFT INC", "CELGENE CORP /DE/", "Scripps Networks Interactive, Inc.", 
"CME GROUP INC.", "QWEST COMMUNICATIONS INTERNATIONAL INC", "NORTH FORK BANCORPORATION INC", 
"PROCTER & GAMBLE Co", "XEROX CORP", "FIRST SOLAR, INC.", "GREAT LAKES CHEMICAL CORP", 
"COMCAST CORP", "KEYCORP /NEW/", "MARTIN MARIETTA MATERIALS INC", 
"Chubb Ltd", "Intercontinental Exchange, Inc.", "REYNOLDS AMERICAN INC", 
"Ingersoll-Rand plc", "RED HAT INC", "American Airlines Group Inc.", 
"FORT JAMES CORP", "HEALTH MANAGEMENT ASSOCIATES, INC", "Owens Corning", 
"DTE ENERGY CO", "CARDINAL HEALTH INC", "WINN DIXIE STORES INC", 
"FOOT LOCKER, INC.", "PINNACLE WEST CAPITAL CORP", "TechnipFMC plc", 
"ONEOK INC /NEW/", "BURLINGTON NORTHERN SANTA FE, LLC", "CIMAREX ENERGY CO", 
"People's United Financial, Inc.", "DOLLAR GENERAL CORP", "IRON MOUNTAIN INC", 
"NAVIENT CORP", "Viacom Inc.", "DUN & BRADSTREET CORP/NW", "Alphabet Inc.", 
"Fortive Corp", "OWENS ILLINOIS INC /DE/", "Discover Financial Services", 
"APPLIED MICRO CIRCUITS CORP", "AMERIPRISE FINANCIAL INC", "Medtronic plc", 
"AMETEK INC/", "EQUINIX INC", "UNIVISION COMMUNICATIONS INC", 
"Altice USA, Inc."), filing_date_year = c(2019L, 2008L, 2015L, 
2013L, 2010L, 2011L, 2005L, 2007L, 2004L, 2013L, 2006L, 2015L, 
2018L, 2017L, 2015L, 2007L, 2016L, 2004L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2015L, 2008L, 2009L, 2011L, 2011L, 2018L, 2003L, 2011L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2014L, 2008L, 2008L, 2019L, 2010L, 2012L, 2008L, 2014L, 
2016L, 2013L, 2013L, 2011L, 2011L, 2003L, 2014L, 2015L, 2013L, 
2007L, 2016L, 2009L, 2009L, 2005L, 2008L, 2011L, 2018L, 2006L, 
2012L, 2005L, 2018L, 2004L, 2017L, 2011L, 2018L, 2014L, 2019L, 
2017L, 2006L, 2011L, 2017L, 2009L, 2009L, 2018L, 2017L, 2005L, 
2016L, 2014L, 2018L, 2007L, 2007L, 2012L, 2011L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2019L, 2009L, 2013L, 2014L, 2012L, 2003L, 2011L, 2006L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2017L, 2015L, 2011L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT:

If the data is called `d` and the directory is as follows `D:/SPY_data/` then this starts downloading the data.

```
library(purrr)
walk2(d$href.y, d$CIKAccNumFileDate_web_extension,
      function(x, y) {
        download.file(x, destfile = paste0("D:/SPY_data/", y), quiet = FALSE)
      })
```

This downloads the files in a single folder, however I hope to have the files in multiple folders by years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, I first create all the year directories and than I download the files

```
library(purrr)
walk(as.vector(paste0("D:/SPY_data/", d$filing_date_year)), dir.create)

walk2(d$href.y,
      paste(d$filing_date_year, d$CIKAccNumFileDate_web_extension,
            sep = "/"),
      function(x, y) {
        download.file(x, 
                      destfile = paste0("D:/SPY_data/", y),
                      quiet = FALSE)
      })
```

Comment: I am applying it to the whole data and it seems to be working well! Thanks. Awesome sorting solution to the collection of these documents :) I am watching it sort and file all these documents and its like I have my own filing secretary.